# Use a cachebuster with asp.net mvc 4 bundling

Tags: caching, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I'm using the standard asp.net mvc bundler from the System.Web.Optimizations namespace.

One of my css bundles contains some css files that have been changing frequently.

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Styles/core").Include(
    "~/Styles/main.css",
    "~/Styles/somepage.css"
    ));
```

How do I configure a cachebuster for this? The scripts are included with

```
@Styles.Render("~/Styles/core")
```

Thanks to the [Oaf.DeploymentInfo package](https://bitbucket.org/oliverwymantechssg/oaf.deploymentinfo) (disclaimer: I'm the author) I have my current revision available in the `Oaf.DeploymentInfo.Revision` static string on the server and `ow.revision` in the browser.

Comment: What problem are you having specifically? Bundling already accounts for files changing frequently.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev - The problem is that occasionally I'll change main.css and deploy changes, yet until my users clear their cache they're still seeing the old main.css. I have the revision # available programamtically so it is already the ideal cachebuster, I just need to know how to hook it up.

Comment: They shouldn't be seeing main.css at all. They should be seeing something like `/styles/core?v=something`. Where `v` will change everytime you update main.css, forcing the client to download the new bundle. If they are seeing `/styles/main.css` in a `link href=` then you are not bundling.

Comment: As in, likely either `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false` is set or you are running in Debug mode.

Comment: Indeed you are correct - I have optimizations disabled. Well in that case, in keeping with the initial thrust of the question - is there a way to use my own cachebreaker rather than the builtin one?

Comment: IMO the easiest way to answer the original question of "How do I configure a cachebuster for this?" is to enable optimizations. If you don't want to use the built-in bundling and minification, there are likely other projects out there do this that you could probably find and look at for ideas. IDK off top of my head though, sorry.